# File copy in shell script based on mysql entry

Tags: mysql, shell

I need to run few copy commands sequentially one after another , However I can use sleep command to run this sequentially. Once execute the copy command which will mark two entries immediately to the mysql table with random_id and status as pending , I need to run the second command only after the status changed to success . how can I do it simply in shell script

command

```
aws s3 cp firstfile1.txt /path
```

Once after the command is triggered , in Mysql , we can see entry like this

```
entry_date , random_id , status,id 
2019-03-10 , FIlecopy_190223321,pending , 10
2019-03-10 , FIlecopy_part2_190223321,pending , 10
```

Once the status changed to success , automatically should trigger the second file copy.

```
aws s3 cp secondfile.txt /path
```

Mysql entries

```
 2019-03-10 , secondfilecopy_11111,pending , 11
 2019-03-10 , secondfilecopy_part_2_11111,pending , 11
```

and the list goes on for 1000 files . How can I achieve this simply in shell script.

Can anyone help me on this.Solution below didnt help me properly,

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are just looking for the way to add conditions based on the mysql records in db.

As you can just fetch records and add condtion based on thier status in db.

Here is very cool solutions provided.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111545/mysql-query-resultset-in-bash-script

Here is example to add conditions from mysql records.

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql --silent -h server-name -P 3306 -u username-ppassword -D dbname<<<"select URL  from Experiment where URL_Exists = 1" > tmp_results

while read URL
do 
   echo $URL
   var=$(curl -s --head $URL | head -n 1 | grep "HTTP/1.[01] [23]..")
   echo "$var"
   if [ -z "$var" ]
   then
     echo "Ok we do not have a valid link and the value needs to be updated as -1 here"
   else
     echo "we will update the value as 1 from here"
   fi
done < tmp_results
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, I'll follow... here I have just tried to hightlight the key points and referenced the solutions link. I have updated the answers.

Comment: this is not helping.My unique ID is 10 and random id is keep on changing once you initiate the copy command. If you want to sort based on id.it is tough to identify the unique id as it generates only after the time you initiate thecopy command

Comment: If you would like to copy one file at a moment... just verify If there is any pending record exists in db don't start copy of next file... else process the file which status is success.